# Can't mount Windows share through cifs Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: mount, windows-7, shared-folders, cifs

I've been trying for a couple hours to find out why I can't access a shared drive on my Windows machine from an Ubuntu machine. I've gotten as far as

```
Retrying with upper case share name
mount error(6): No such device or address
```

and I can't figure out why it can't find the folder. The only thing I can think of is that it's not a member of the workgroup, but my workgroup is WORKGROUP, and I believe that's the default in CIFS as well (which replaces Samba). I have found out how to view/change the workgroup in Samba, but not in CIFS.

Here's the line in the fstab file:

```
//192.168.1.104/share_name  /media/share  cifs  username=username,password=password,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,user  0  0
```

Of course share_name, share, username, and password are replaced with the proper information.

Can anyone tell me why I can't see that share drive? Oh, and I can successfully ping the Windows PC, btw.

Comment: `WORKGROUP` is the default. I think you can add a `workgroup=MY-WORKGROUP` option to your `fstab` if it was different tho.

Comment: Is the share already mounted when you try to access the share? Find out with `findmnt`-command.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that error usually means that the share `share_name` does not exist.

Make sure you're sharing it right in Windows and you're using the right share name.

You can check with `smbclient` (`sudo apt-get install smbclient`) what's being shared:

```
$ smbclient -L 192.168.1.104 -U username
Enter username's password:
Domain=[DOMAIN] OS=[Windows 10 Enterprise 14393] Server=[Windows 10 Enterprise 6.3]

    Sharename       Type      Comment
    ---------       ----      -------
    share_name      Disk     
    ...
```

(I get a couple warnings about logging being disabled and stuff that I omitted.)